# Assessing classification error with synthetic oversampling (SMOTE, ADASYN, et)

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, model-evaluation, oversampling

Consider a situation, where there are two unbalanced classes (n1 < n2). Some standard statistical methods advise to use SMOTE (or similar) oversampling methods to balance classes and train a classifier on balanced classes.

**Here is my question**: how to assess properly a classification error of the trained classifier (or any other metrics, f1, etc)? Remember, the classifier is trained on the augmented dataset (balanced).

Does cross validation on the augmented dataset make sense? I was told, that assessing a performance of the classifier (which is trained on balanced data) should be done only on the original unbalanced dataset.

**UPD**
Here is [a nice paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4634915/pdf/12859_2015_Article_784.pdf) addressing exactly the same problem of CV with SMOTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross validation on the SMOTE-augmented dataset doesn't make sense, because:

1. it would contaminate the training sets with the test sets.
2. it changes the test sets.

You should apply SMOTE only to the training set, i.e. without using the test set. If you want to report cross-validation results, at each iteration of the cross-validation, you should apply SMOTE to the training set.

Comment: thanks for amazing answer! But I don't quite understand, how SMOTE may affect the training set (contaminate/changes). Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: The caret documentation on dealing with imbalanced classes might be helpful to look at for some clarification: https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html

Comment: @dmartin, Does the problem of "contamination" of the test set in CV come from the fact, that oversampling techniques may replicate exactly the same data and in CV process, the same data points (the original, and the replicated one) may appear in both, training and the test sets simultaneously?

Comment: @ArnoldKlein correct, either exact or approximate replicate